# Select sum Command with date range

Tags: sql

how to use sum command with date range? i am used following code but not working. How can i sum with date range?

```
        string str = "select sum(Amount)from tblRecovery where [TDate] between @FromDate and ToDate";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(str, conn.con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FromDate", dateTimePicker1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ToDate", dateTimePicker2);
        txtAmount.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.con.Close();
```

Comment: this is a sql question, not C#

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The code snippet you posted does not indicate where you have told SQL Server what the values of `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` are. You need to add parameters to your OleDbCommand object. You should also tag this question with the kind of DBMS you're using.

Comment: i have edited the code but not working.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich error is "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: Forgot the `@` for `@ToDate`?  Btw, a BETWEEN is fine if TDate is a DATE type, but be carefull if it's a DATETIME.  F.e.  '2020-01-02 00:01:00' is not between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-02'.

Comment: @LukStorms thanks for your reply. I used @ and data field is datetime 2020-01-91 but not working.

Comment: Also use `@` in the AddWithValue's ? [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8).  And wouldn't it need something like  command.Parameters.Add ?

Answer (score 0):

As @LukStorms said in his comment, you need the @ signs in the AddWithValue call as well.

```
        string str = "select sum(Amount)from tblRecovery where [TDate] between @FromDate and ToDate";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(str, conn.con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", dateTimePicker1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", dateTimePicker2);
        txtAmount.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.con.Close();
```